# Bitbucket Rest Api get difference b/w two branches

Tags: git, rest, bitbucket, bitbucket-server, bitbucket-api

I'm trying to find out an end point to get difference between two branches via BitBucket Rest API

```
branch 1: refs/heads/release/1.1
branch 2: refs/heads/release/1.2
```

However when i invoke GET request like

```
https://stash.xx.com:1111/rest/api/1.0/projects/MyProject/repos/repos1/compare/diff?targetBranch=refs%2Fheads%2Frelease%2F1.1&sourceBranch=refs%2Fheads%2Frelease%2F1.2&targetRepoId=123456
```

and HTTP 200 and empty json:

```
{
"fromHash": "refs/heads/master",
"toHash": "refs/heads/master",
"contextLines": 10,
"whitespace": "SHOW",
"diffs": [],
"truncated": false
}
```

the similar ULR i have when comparing the same branches via Bitbucket Web.

I believe i can retrieve commit/message info by:

```
git log --oneline refs/heads/release/1.2...refs/heads/release/1.1
```

but would like to use REST API not through calling git commands directly

Can you give me a hint what i missed?

Thank you

**EDIT**

Resulting JSON includes 'From'  & 'To' default values (default branch) and that's why diff = []

So the issue was definitely in my request's parameters, server could not recognize my fromHash and toHash branches

**RESOLVED**

My bad: incorrect naming of parameters, instead of fromHash/ToHash just do what the [Atlassian doc](https://docs.atlassian.com/bitbucket-server/rest/6.9.1/bitbucket-rest.html#idp205) tells you (**from**, **to**)!

```
https://stash.xx.com:1111/rest/api/1.0/projects/MyProject/repos/repos1/compare/diff?from=refs%2Fheads%2Frelease%2F1.1&to=refs%2Fheads%2Frelease%2F1.2&targetRepoId=123456
```

To have difference in COMMITS just use the same request but **/commits** end point (not diff)

Comment: Would love to see this answer from Bitbucket API 2.0 if anyone knows how to re-format the query.